# Lambda@Edge - You cannot update the specified distribution using this API version because it is associated with a cache policy

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to setup Lambda@Edge but getting the following error on clicking `Deploy to Lambda@Edge` button.

> You cannot update the specified distribution using this API version because it is associated with a cache policy.

My CloudFront distribution is already ready and is in `Deployed` state.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: AWS is amazing sometimes. Is there seriously no way to solve this that does no rely on going back to using LEGACY settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching to 'Legacy cache settings'. I got the lead from this link:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=950582

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Had this error :**

```
You cannot update the specified distribution using this API version because it is associated with a cache policy. 
(Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: IllegalUpdate;
 Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-49c2-b15e-6xxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)
```

To solve :

- I had cached policy already at 'Legacy cache settings'
- Switched it back to managed optimised cache policy
- Switched again to 'Legacy cache settings'

After this, error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Had same error trying to make some changes with terraform, you need to follow this steps to solve it:

- Go to `Cloudfront` on the AWS console.
- Choose your Cloudfront distribution.
- Click on the `Behaviours` and choose edit on your origin.
- On `Cache and origin request settings` choose `Use legacy cache settings`
- Now you can customise the cache TTL values (Recommended: `Minimum TTL: 0`. `Maximum TTL: 31536000`, `Default TTL: 86400`).